# Lazy Android dependencies. How to build AARs libraries before gradle dependency resolution

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I have this simplified project schema of a closed source group of libraries:

```
- app
  > references library1, library2
- library1
- library2
  > references library3
- library3
```

All 3 libraries produce `aar` files which can be referenced in the app dependencies as usual.

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":library1")
    implementation project(":library2")
}
```

**The problem start when I want to test my app with obfuscated `aar`s** (builded in release mode). Currently the Android Plugin ignores this so the only way i've found is to do this with pre-built aars.

```
dependencies {
    //for debug build just use the local project
    debugImplementation project(":library1")
    debugImplementation project(":library2")
    //for release build use manually added aar in libs folder
    releaseImplementation (name: 'library1-release', ext: 'aar')
    releaseImplementation (name: 'library2-release', ext: 'aar')
    //i need to add library3 too otherwise it will not find
    //method referenced there because aar are not bundled togheter
    //by default
    releaseImplementation (name: 'library3-release', ext: 'aar')
}
```

And this works fine.

To do this I've created a small script like this (in app/scripts/build-aar.sh)

```
//move from scripts folder to root project folder
cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/../../"
//assembleRelease all the aar (which enables Proguard obfuscation)
./gradlew clean assembleRelease --info &&
//copy them in the app libs folder
cp -rf library1/build/outputs/aar/library1-release.aar app/libs/library1-release.aar
cp -rf library2/build/outputs/aar/library2-release.aar app/libs/library2-release.aar
cp -rf library3/build/outputs/aar/library3-release.aar app/libs/library3-release.aar
```

The problem with this approach is that I need to version all the aar in git, otherwise the app doesn't compile when i select "Release" as build variant.

While I would to gitignore all the aar in the libs folder and build them on the fly before app search for it's dependencies.

I've tried with something like this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        variant.preBuildProvider.configure {
            dependsOn(buildReleaseAar)
        }
    }
}

task buildReleaseAar {
    dependsOn (
        ':library1:assembleRelease',
        ':library2:assembleRelease',
        ':library3:assembleRelease'
    )
    doLast {
        //copy the aars from build folders in app/libs folder
    }
}
```

But the dependencies are checked before so I can't even sync the project anymore without having the aars in the libs folder.

---

The pseudo-logic for solve this problem should be:

1) Having a new task for the dependencies like (obfuscatedAar)

2) Having this task to check if there are aars in the libs folder, if not to run assembleRelease on all 3 libraries and copy resulting AARs there

Something like this:

```
configurations {
    releaseObfuscatedAar
}

dependencies {
    //other implementations libs

    //for debug build just use the local project
    debugImplementation project(":library1")
    debugImplementation project(":library2")

    releaseObfuscatedAar('library1')
    releaseObfuscatedAar('library2')
    releaseObfuscatedAar('library3')
}

//and some other task that build the aar before checking if
//dependency is present
```

> Questions:
>
> - Is this possible?
> - Is this a good approach to test my proguard-rules added in libraries projects (and be sure I didn't broke public API when
>     obfuscation is on)?

---

[Reference to same question in Gradle Forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/lazy-resolution-of-dependencies-in-android/31762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am aware my answer comes a bit late.

I faced a similar issue and I solved it by relying on the local maven repository, being the default one located in `~/.m2`.

My approach at the beginning was basically making my `:app:assemble${variant.name}` task depend on `:my-library:publishToMavenLocal`.

This approach kind of works, but the `dependencies {...}` block is still evaluated before the library puts its `aar` under the local maven repository. Also, the `assemble` tasks are not run if you just sync the project in Android Studio/IntelliJ.

Therefore this is what I did in the end:

`tasks.getByPath(":prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel").dependsOn(":library:publishToMavenLocal")`

which makes the local maven repo be populated with your `aar` when syncing the project, so the dependency on those `aar`s is satisfied in a later step.

Don't forget to add `mavenLocal()` in your `repositories {...}` closure, if you want to give it a try.

Of course, this solution comes with a cost, which is the local maven deploy on every sync. In my case, it's relatively fast (due to the gradle cache), but just saying :)

Comment: In the end we solved it by publishing on an internal maven repository but the solution is similar to yours. Sorry I forgot to accept the answer :)